# R: remove every word that ends with ".htm"

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a df = desc with a variable "value" that holds long text and would like to remove every word in that variable that ends with ".htm" . I looked for a long time around here and regex expressions and cannot find a solution.

Can anyone help? Thank you so much!

I tried things like:

```
library(stringr)
desc <- str_replace_all(desc$value, "\*.htm*$", "")
```

But I get:

```
Error: '\*' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\*"
```

Comment: Pls give examples of the strings in question. Do they contain just one 'word' or several, as suggested by 'text', which you use. It's also unclear whether you want to remove the ending`.html` or the whole word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex:

- Will Catch all that ends with `.htm`
- Will **not** catch instances with `.html`
- Is not dependent on being in the beginning / end of a string.

```r
strings <- c("random text shouldbematched.htm notremoved.html matched.htm random stuff")

gsub("\\w+\\.htm\\b", "", strings)
```

Output:

```r
[1] "random text  notremoved.html  random stuff"
```

Comment: Wow! It is the first time I ask a question here and I am amazed with the speed and amount of responses: thank you so much wonderful people! This answer is exactly what I was looking for and thank you also for nuancing it to a code that would keep in ".html" but remove ".htm"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you would like to accomplish, but I guess one of those is what you are looking for:

```
words <- c("apple", "test.htm", "friend.html", "remove.htm")

# just replace the ".htm" from every string
str_replace_all(words, ".htm", "")

# exclude all words that contains .htm anywhere
words[!grepl(pattern = ".htm", words)]

# exlude all words that END with .htm
words[substr(words, nchar(words)-3, nchar(words)) != ".htm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can use * to tell R to consider any value inside a string, so I would first remove it. Also, in your code you are setting a change in your variable "value" to replace the entire df.

So I would suggest the following:

```
desc$value <- str_replace(desc$value, ".htm", "")
```

By doing so, you are telling R to remove all .htm that you have in the desc$value variable alone. I hope it works!

Comment: I am afraid OP wants to remove >>every word in that variable that ends with ".htm"<< :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want just do:

```
desc$value <- str_replace(desc$value, ".*\\.htm$", "")
```

---

You are trying to escape the star and it is useless. You get an error because `\*` does not exist in R strings. You just have `\n`, `\t` etc...

`\.` does not exist either in R strings. But `\\` exists and it produces a single `\` in the resulting string used for the regular expression. Therefore, when you escape something in a R regexp you have to escape it twice:

In my regexp:  `.*` means any chars and `\\.` means a real dot. I have to escape it twice because `\` needs to be escape first from the R string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have, as you say, a variable "value" that holds long text and you want to remove every word that ends in `.html`. Based on these assumptions you can use `str_remove all`:

The main point here is to wrap the pattern into word boundary markers `\\b`:

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(value, "\\b\\w+\\.html\\b")
[1] "apple  and test2.html01" "the word  must etc. and  as well" "we want to remove .htm"
```

Data:

```
value <- c("apple test.html and test2.html01", 
           "the word friend.html must etc. and x.html as well", 
           "we want to remove .htm")
```